# Prove that $A \cup C \sim A$ when $C$ is countable and $A$ is infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

First of all, if $A$ is countable, the result is true because the union of countable sets is countable. If $A$ is uncountable, and I have no idea how to prove this part.

Can it be useful? is there a better way to prove this?

Thanks.

Comment: If $A$ is infinite it contains a countably infinite subset $A'$. Now just define a map that fixes everything in $A - A'$ and maps $A' \cup C$ to $A'$ bijectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us solve the case $ \#C=\infty$.

As $A$ is infinite, it has a subset $A'$ such as $A'\sim C$.
Now consider a bijection $f: C\to A'\cup C$ (such an object exist: we can suppose that $C\sim\Bbb N$ and $A'\cup C\sim\Bbb Z$ and there is an explicit bijection between these two) and define 
$$
g:A \to A\cup C
$$
with $g(x) = f(x)$ if $x\in A'$, $g(x)=x$ otherwise. This is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Write $A$ as a disjoint union of $A'$ and $ A\setminus A'$, where $A'$ is countable.